# Передача переменных в массив

Tags: javascript, php, битрикс, 1с

Прошу не пинать сильно, кодированием PHP особо не занимался. Задача следующая: устанавливается в карточку товара кнопка по рассрочке юмани. Подробной документации нет. В данной части кода как мне передать переменную PHP в скрипт в значение **sum**? Или может я вообще не правильно все делаю? Заранее спасибо.

```
<script src="https://static.yoomoney.ru/checkout-credit-ui/v1/index.js"></script>
<script> 
    const $checkoutCreditUI = CheckoutCreditUI({
    shopId: '6677';
    sum: '<?= $minPrice['VALUE'];?>'
    });
                            
    const checkoutCreditText = $checkoutCreditUI({
    type: 'info',
    domSelector: '.parent3'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добавить `hidden`  поле с нужным Вам `id` и в `js` получать его значение. Либо навешать на какой-то элемент страницы `data`-атрибут с этим же значением иопять же в `js` получить его значение.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Обязательное поле "идентификатор магазина", это и так понятно, но без него не будет работать скрипт в принципе, так как условия расчета получает по нему. Ну и кавычки не нужны.

```
<script src="https://static.yoomoney.ru/checkout-credit-ui/v1/index.js"></script>
<script> 
    const $checkoutCreditUI = CheckoutCreditUI({
    shopId: '**ХХХХХХ**';
    sum: <?= $minPrice['VALUE'];?>
    });
                            
    const checkoutCreditText = $checkoutCreditUI({
    type: 'info',
    domSelector: '.parent3'
    });
</script>
```